# Setting a mountpoint as immutable with ansible makes the mounted volume unable to be written, while it works manually

Tags: ansible

As a force of habit after losing several hundred TB of data in the past during a NAS outage, I always set mountpoints on servers to be immutable. It prevents any changes to the disk structure underneath the mountpoint. This prevents a scenario where a disk mounted at that mountpoint becomes disconnected, and the kernel starts writing those files to the mountpoint instead. Making it immutable prevents the root volume from filling up, and causes the security bells to start screaming which helps us notice the issue more quickly.

This works just fine normally. If I create /mnt/mountpoint, and make it immutable, I can't create any files there as root. If I mount a volume at /mnt/mountpoint, I can create test files there without a problem.

```
[root@test-vm-1 ~]# mkdir /mnt/test
[root@test-vm-1 ~]# touch /mnt/test/testfile
[root@test-vm-1 ~]# ls /mnt/test/testfile
/mnt/test/testfile
[root@test-vm-1 ~]# rm -f /mnt/test/testfile
[root@test-vm-1 ~]# chattr +i /mnt/test/
[root@test-vm-1 ~]# touch /mnt/test/testfile
touch: cannot touch `/mnt/test/testfile': Permission denied
[root@bcv-ub-test-vm-1 ~]# mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1
mke2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
TEXT OMMITTED
[root@test-vm-1 ~]# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/test/
[root@test-vm-1 ~]# touch /mnt/test/testfile
[root@test-vm-1 ~]# umount /mnt/test
[root@test-vm-1 ~]# umount /mnt/test/testfile
umount: /mnt/test/testfile: not found
[root@test-vm-1 ~]# touch /mnt/test/testfile
touch: cannot touch `/mnt/test/testfile': Permission denied
```

So, the behavior is that you can't write to the mountpoint unless a volume is mounted there.

However, I use a playbook to run the following in ansible:

```
- name: Validate that VIVALogger volume group is created and added
  stat:
    path: /dev/sdb1
  register: stat_result

- name: Configure export volume - add mountpoint
  file:
    path: /mnt/test
    state: directory

- name: Make test mountpoint immutable
  command: "chattr +i /mnt/test"

- name: Configure export volume - mount export volume
  mount:
    path: /mnt/test
    src: /dev/sdb1
    fstype: xfs
    state: mounted
    opts: inode64,nobarrier
    dump: 0
    passno: 2
  when: stat_result.stat.exists

- name: Pause for 30 seconds for volume to mount properly
  pause:
    seconds: 30

- name: Create testfile
  command: "touch /mnt/test/testfile"
```

No files can be written to the mounted volume. It seems like the immutability is being recursively applied to all subdirectories of the volume.

I have also attempted to configure immutability using the file module, and the behavior is the same.

Has anyone seen this behavior before? I'm using ansible 2.6.3 against RHEL 5, 6 and 7.

Comment: This only does what you want when there is not a filesystem mounted at the time you run `chattr`. This is something you should check for before running the `command`. It sounds like the filesystem is already mounted at the time `chattr` runs.

Comment: So, you think it could be a race condition? At least in the role, the mount happens after setting the immutable flag. I guess I can time how long setting the immutable bit takes, or just try it with a pause in place.

Comment: Hrm, I would be tempted to try switching your `command:` to `shell: "stat /mnt/test ; chattr +i /mnt/test"` and then run ansible with -vv and see if you can see what is going on.

Comment: Are you running this playbook repeatedly? Yes? Did you _umount_ the filesystem between runs?